# Keras The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

i've a problem with my code, the code is for Cancer detection, other piece of code i have running well but when reaching to the keras.fit_generator() i got this error ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all() on my keras.fit_generator() model, the error is on M=model.fit_generator(),as you can see my code below other part of the code runs well but the problem is on the keras.fit_generator(), differentes parameters of the keras.fit_generator() are valide but i don't know where i made a mistake, i'm new in deep learning so please help me
find my code down

```
matplotlib.use("Agg")

from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.callbacks import LearningRateScheduler
from keras.optimizers import Adagrad
from keras.utils import np_utils
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from cancernet.cancernet import CancerNet
from cancernet import config
from imutils import paths
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import os

NUM_EPOCHS=40; INIT_LR=1e-2; BS=32

trainPaths=list(paths.list_images(config.TRAIN_PATH))
lenTrain=len(trainPaths)
lenVal=len(list(paths.list_images(config.VAL_PATH)))
lenTest=len(list(paths.list_images(config.TEST_PATH)))

trainLabels=[int(p.split(os.path.sep)[-2]) for p in trainPaths]
trainLabels=np_utils.to_categorical(trainLabels)
classTotals=trainLabels.sum(axis=0)
classWeight=classTotals.max()/classTotals

trainAug = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1/255.0,
    rotation_range=20,
    zoom_range=0.05,
    width_shift_range=0.1,
    height_shift_range=0.1,
    shear_range=0.05,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    vertical_flip=True,
    fill_mode="nearest")

valAug=ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1 / 255.0)

trainGen = trainAug.flow_from_directory(
    config.TRAIN_PATH,
    class_mode="categorical",
    target_size=(48,48),
    color_mode="rgb",
    shuffle=True,
    batch_size=BS)
valGen = valAug.flow_from_directory(
    config.VAL_PATH,
    class_mode="categorical",
    target_size=(48,48),
    color_mode="rgb",
    shuffle=False,
    batch_size=BS)
testGen = valAug.flow_from_directory(
    config.TEST_PATH,
    class_mode="categorical",
    target_size=(48,48),
    color_mode="rgb",
    shuffle=False,
    batch_size=BS)

model=CancerNet.build(width=48,height=48,depth=3,classes=2)
opt=Adagrad(lr=INIT_LR,decay=INIT_LR/NUM_EPOCHS)
model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy",optimizer=opt,metrics=["accuracy"])

M=model.fit_generator(
    trainGen,
    steps_per_epoch=lenTrain//BS,
    validation_data=valGen,
    validation_steps=lenVal//BS,
    class_weight=classWeight,
    epochs=NUM_EPOCHS)

print("Now evaluating the model")
testGen.reset()
pred_indices=model.predict_generator(testGen,steps=(lenTest//BS)+1)

pred_indices=np.argmax(pred_indices,axis=1)

print(classification_report(testGen.classes, pred_indices, target_names=testGen.class_indices.keys()))

cm=confusion_matrix(testGen.classes,pred_indices)
total=sum(sum(cm))
accuracy=(cm[0,0]+cm[1,1])/total
specificity=cm[1,1]/(cm[1,0]+cm[1,1])
sensitivity=cm[0,0]/(cm[0,0]+cm[0,1])
print(cm)
print(f'Accuracy: {accuracy}')
print(f'Specificity: {specificity}')
print(f'Sensitivity: {sensitivity}')

N = NUM_EPOCHS
plt.style.use("ggplot")
plt.figure()
plt.plot(np.arange(0,N), M.history["loss"], label="train_loss")
plt.plot(np.arange(0,N), M.history["val_loss"], label="val_loss")
plt.plot(np.arange(0,N), M.history["acc"], label="train_acc")
plt.plot(np.arange(0,N), M.history["val_acc"], label="val_acc")
plt.title("Training Loss and Accuracy on the IDC Dataset")
plt.xlabel("Epoch No.")
plt.ylabel("Loss/Accuracy")
plt.legend(loc="lower left")
plt.savefig('plot.png')
```

Comment: That error comes from trying to evaluate an array as a boolean, like so:
a = np.array([False, False,  True])
if a:
     print("boom!")
My guess is that the output of the network is designed for multiclass, so outputs an array of length 2. The loss function might be the source of the error. Categorical cross entropy might work. Or converting output to a single value, if I'm right about the shape of the output. Good luck!

Comment: A full error traceback might help.  It should tell us (and YOU) what is being tested.  It may be nested deep in some other code, but we might be able to trace it back to your inputs.  Something about your arguments is wrong.  A common problem with `keras` inputs is that they are "ragged", uneven, and don't form regular numeric dtype arrays.  You/we need to determine what is about your arguments (arrays or tensors) that don't match the program's expectations.  Make sure you reread the relevant documentation.   **Don't ignore the documentation**